# Cannot generate code for a simple example in OpenModelica

Tags: openmodelica

I am trying to compile a simple example in OpenModelica in Linux. The contents of the `HelloWorld.om` file are the following:

```
class Main
  Real x(start = 1, fixed = true);
  parameter Real a = 1;
equation
  der(x) = -a*x;
end Main;
```

I am calling the OpenModelica compiler as follows to produce the `Main` executable file:

```bash
 omc --simulationCg HelloWorld.om
```

However, the compilation returns the error message

```
Error processing file: HelloWorld.om
# Error encountered! Exiting...
# Please check the error message and the flags.

Execution failed!
```

and exits with code `1`.

When running the simulation from a script, `runHelloWorld.mos`, with content

```
loadFile("HelloWorld.om");
simulate(Main, stopTime=2);
plot(x);
```

by calling

```
omc runHelloWorls.mos
```

the file is compiled producing the `Main` executable, which is then used to generate the output of the simulation without any issues.

Why does the stand alone compilation of `HelloWorld.om` fail?

Comment: Works for me (Windows, self-build OpenModelica, v1.22.0-dev-285).
What version of OpenModelica are you using?
Also note, that this won't compile the generated C files.

Comment: According to `omc --version` I am using `OpenModelica 1.21.0~2-g0bc3d29`. OpenModelica is installed from the [official repository for Debian 12](https://openmodelica.org/download/download-linux/). I would like to have the C files, as long as `Main.makefile` is also generated.

Comment: The problem is that you named your file .om instead of .mo. If you run with omc -s Model.mo it will generate the code but then you need to compile the code: make -f Model.makefile.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the file extension.